# Make existing visual studio project as repository git (local network)

Tags: git, git-repo

I have many projects hosted in the server and I would like to turn them into repositories to reach in the internal network.
Actually, the projects are on a server folder, I would like to move them to another folder on the same server and use them as a repository, where we will work in three people.
How can I do that?

I've already tried to make the folder as repo, with init and `--bare`. But I would like to know if there is a faster process to transfer multiple project folders into repo server